# ¿Porque no imprime etiqueta HTML después de hacer el .map?

Tags: html, reactjs

Mi problema está en que no imprime el código HTML que está en el return de esta función `categoriesHome`. El `console.log()` imprime bien los datos pero lo que está dentro del return no se refleja a pesar de que sí entra cuando coloco un `debugger;`.

Como puedo resolver este problema?

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles/categories.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

class Categories extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.categories = props.allCategories
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className = "categories-sectios">
        <div className = "row justify-content-center">
        {
          categoriesHome(this.categories)
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function categoriesHome(data){
  data.map(map => {
    console.log(map)
    return(
      <div className = "col-4">
        <p>{map.categorie}</p>
      </div>
    )
  })
}

export default Categories
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pasa esto porque no devuelves el array que creas con el `map`. Te falta el `return`.

```
function categoriesHome(data){
  return data.map(map => {
    console.log(map)
    return(
      <div className = "col-4">
        <p>{map.categorie}</p>
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Por otro lado, en vez de hacerlo así puedes crearlo como un componente hijo que reciba por props las categorías y las renderice. Así sigues más el patrón de `react`. Ten en cuenta que el nombre de los componentes tiene que empezar por mayúscula para que react pueda diferenciar entre un componente custom y los elementos nativos de html.

```
class Categories extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.categories = props.allCategories
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="categories-sectios">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <CategoriesHome data={this.categories}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function CategoriesHome(props){
// puedes usar destructuring pero eso ya es decisión tuya
// function CategoriesHome({ data }){

  return props.data.map(item => {
    return(
      <div className="col-4" key={item.categorie}>
        <p>{item.categorie}</p>
      </div>
    )
  })
}

export default Categories
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo y claro que tendré en cuenta los comentarios que añadiste

Comment: si te sirvió acepta la respuesta dando al check(✓) que hay a la izquierda de la respuesta. Gracias